# Why does the assumption $|U_t| \le \frac1{p_{\min}}$ work in this paper?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, machine-learning

I am reading a 2009 paper right now ["Importance Weighted Active Learning"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4952.pdf) and on page 5, there is a theorem that uses the inequality $|U_t| \leq \frac{1}{p_{\min}}$. I am not sure how the paper found this assumption.

Theorem in question:

[image: Theorem in question]

---

The theorem is for this importance weighted active learning algorithm:

[image: The theorem is for this importance weighted active learning algorithm]

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to MO. I suggest you seriously edit your question, so that someone could read it without going through papers. Surely, you can write a self-contained question so that an expert can read it and respond. As it is, most chances you won't receive help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper,
\begin{equation}
 U_t=\frac{Q_t}{p_t}\,l(h(x_t),y_t)-L(h)
\end{equation}
and $p_{\min}=\min_t p_t$, 
where the values of $Q_t$ are in $\{0,1\}$ and the values of $p_t$ are in $[0,1]$. It appears that the condition that the values of the loss function $l$ are also in $[0,1]$ is missing in the paper before Theorem 1 on page 5; however, on page 6 I see "Since the loss values are normalized to lie in $[0, 1]$". Assuming that condition, we see that $L(h)$, being an expected value of $l$, is in $[0, 1]$ as well and hence in $[0,1/p_{\min}]$. So, $U_t$ is the difference of two values, each of them in $[0,1/p_{\min}]$. So, $|U_t|\le1/p_{\min}$.

Of course, without the condition that the values of $l$ are in $[0,1]$, the conclusion $|U_t|\le1/p_{\min}$ would in general be false.